# Problems with hidden div, why doesn't it work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have already looked at several examples here on this site but my problem still persists.

Let me explain briefly: I have a series of if / if else that must return the corresponding div to me, based on the type. And so far there are no problems.

Now I want that, in case the type is missing, it will return me a hidden div, therefore not visible

I tried as written below, but for example, if the youtube video is missing, a picture with a black border and a white background appears. I would like to eliminate this "picture" because it is not a good practice to show.

How come it doesn't work like I did?

```js
<div class="video"> <iframe id="idframe" width="600" height="400" > </iframe> </div> <br>

else if 
.
.
.
else if (myArray.Items[2].type == "video"){
        document.getElementById("idframe").src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+idurl;
    }
 else if(myArr.Items[2]type == ""){
        document.getElementById("idframe").style.display='none';
    }
```

```css
.video {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the there is an issue with this line:

```js
document.getElementById("").style.display='none';
```

maybe you miss `id` here in `getElementById("")`

Comment: even if I put the id does not work, that empty box always appears

Comment: It seems you are using class attribute, and trying to retrieve id.

Comment: I try to put document.getElementById("idframe").style.display='none'; so with the exact id but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: I am noticing that that if/else statement is not considered. Is it wrong as a syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You stated that if the video is missing, a picture appears.

Have you checked that the array item returns a blank value, and not some other value?
Perhaps it would be better to have a catch all instead:

For example:

```
else {
document.getElementById("idframe").style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: tried this too, but it turns out the same problem

Comment: I am noticing that that if/else statement is not considered. Is it wrong as a syntax?